Dataflow scheduled refresh stops working when I add another Dataflow to the same server
I want 2 Dataflows with scheduled refreshes working in the same server. One Dataflow is for Power BI and the other one is for a dynamic Excel.
So I have a dataflow with some SQL Server views, that refreshes everyday 5 times. This dataflow is for the Power BI let's call it PB Dataflow. The information of the flow comes from a server (with SQL Server) that has a gateway on premise so the Power BI service can update the data from service. This one works fine.
I want a second dataflow with 2 different views for making an excel that refreshes the data with the flow, let's call this the Excel Dataflow. When I try to connect this dataflow it works, but the refresh from the PB Dataflow fails (the refreshes are running at different times, it's not a resource problem from the server).
The PB is made and published from an org account and shared with another account from another organization. The excel needs to be opened with the same account that the PB is shared, the client org, but I can't make it work. If the sharing between the account that is published (the PB) and the account that uses the Report works fine, I don't understand why I can't share the Excel Dataflow.
I tested some things like putting all the views in the PB Dataflow, making a new semantic model with the 2 views for the excel and sharing the semantic model with the other account. This method doesn't work and I don't understand why, in this case the dataflow refreshes fine but I can't access the data from the another account (even than the semantic model is shared and even also I tested sharing the whole workspace). When I try to get the data from dataflow or from power bi in excel, the dataflow doesn't show, and I changed the configuration of the origin of data with the info from the org account. I tested many methods but I can't understand why this fails, I think it's some tenant issue but I don't know how to surpass it.
Hope this explanation was detailed enough, let me know if you need more explanation and thanks in advance.
